# C++ setting attribute of a derived class to an unknown class object, derived from same base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, parent, radix

I have 3 classes, a Base class, a Parent class and a Child class. Parent has `m_children` vector which can have multiple children in it, but a child can only have one parent object as it's `m_parent` attribute. How should I implement this? Here's a quick preview of the classes (rewritten for the sake of the question)

Base.h

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual void getClid();
    virtual void setClid();
private:
    int m_clid;
};
```

Parent.h

```
#include <vector>
#include "Base.h"
#include "Child.h"

class Parent : public Base
{
public:
    Parent();
    void addChild(Child* child);
    void removeChild(Child* child);
    Child* getChild(int index);
private:
    std::vector<Child*> m_children;
};
```

Child.h

```
#include "Base.h"

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    Child();
    Base* getParent();
    void setParent(Base* parent);
private:
    Base* m_parent;
};
```

Now the problem here, as you see, is that I can only include "Parent.h" in "Child.h" OR the other way around, not both. How do I tell Child the type of his parent? Code below works fine, but if I want to call `m_parent->removeChild(this);` for example from Child object's destructor, it won't work cause Child only knows getClid and setClid methods of Parent, which are both defined in "Base.h"

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ creating doubly-linked classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207138/c-creating-doubly-linked-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you can do something like that for Child.h:

```
#include "Base.h"

class ParentObject;

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    Child();
    ParentObject* getParent();
    void setParent(ParentObject* parent);
private:
    ParentObject* m_parent;
};
```

Comment: When using forward declaration, I only receive two errors: `invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Parent'` and `forward declaration of 'struct Inventory'` from line `m_parent->removeItem(this);`

Comment: Don't implement the functions in the header. Implement them in a separate source file and include the parent header there.

Comment: Did you include Parent.h in Child.c ?

Answer (score 0):

You can forward-declare `child` in the Parent header and vice versa, breaking the circular dependency.

```
#include <vector>
#include "Base.h"

class Child;    
class Parent : public Base
{
public:
    Parent();
    void addChild(Child* child);
    void removeChild(Child* child);
    Child* getChild(int index);
private:
    std::vector<Child*> m_children;
};
```

and

```
#include "Base.h"
class Parent;    
class Child : public Base
{
public:
    Child();
    Parent* getParent();
    void setParent(Parent* parent);
private:
    Parent* m_parent;
};
```

But I gotta say, there are way too many raw pointers and too many setters and non-interfaces here. I'm smelling a dodgy design.

Comment: Hmm mind giving some more info? Can't think of a way to do it better.